# How to use variable in Select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need way to call variable in select clause.
Eg. Table name "TableList" contains the list of table names.

```
DECLARE @CounterNumber INT = 1
Declare @name varchar(255)
Set @name = (Select Name from TableList where id = @CounterNumber)
WHILE @CounterNumber <= 3

select top 10 * from @name
set @CounterNumber = @CounterNumber + 1
```

Error Message -
Must declare the table variable "@name".

I used "quotename()" as well but still getting the same error.

Comment: A variable cannot be used to replace the name of a literal. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here? The above would (if it worked as you intended) just `SELECT` 10 arbitrary rows from the same table; which I doubt is intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic SQL:

```
WHILE @CounterNumber <= 3
BEGIN
    SELECT @name Name 
    FROM TableList 
    WHERE id = @CounterNumber;

    DECLARE @sql = NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = 'select top 10 * from @name';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@name', quotename(@name));

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    SET @CounterNumber = @CounterNumber + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Without assigning the value of `@name` this will just run the same query 3 times.